# Cannot open ubuntu 20.06 which is in downloads on my hp pavilion with xp. dualboot

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual-boot and have downloaded ubuntu 20.06 to my hp pavilion running xp, it is in the downloads file. I am unable to get it to open and am not sure of my options, rather green at this. I tried adobe but the just responded that it can't open it, then I tried windows media and that made no sense. How can I open and run this as I want to do away with the xp and make this computer usable again? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to "do away with XP" meaning, wipe it out and put ubuntu on it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to open? If you have the Ubuntu ISO file you need to make a bootable disc or USB in order to boot from it and either use the live version to try it out or use the install option and install Ubuntu onto that PC.

Comment: Welcome! Regarding installation, follow [Ubuntu installation guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview), and about Windows Xp, how old is your computer?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 will only work on 64bit computers, a XP computer might be 64bit or only 32bit.  If computer only 32bit let us know in question and will point you to versions take will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Get a pen drive / HDD with enough space (above 5–6gb is more than enough).

Step 2- Format it by right clicking on the drive and clicking format.

Step 3- Download UNetbootin. This software allows you to create a bootable HDD/pendrive. Do not forget to download the Ubuntu ISO file.

Step 4- if you want to keep Windows XP and Ubuntu, partition your drive. Refer to YouTube tutorials for this because I'm not experienced enough to share this.  If you want to kill Windows XP forever, ignore this.

Step 5- Shut down your PC, connect your pen drive and select boot from USB.  To do this step successfully, you need to know your motherboard model and company as it varies from company to company. Once again, refer to YouTube for this step.

Step 6- Follow the steps and install just like any other windows program.

Step 7- Post installation, enjoy Linux life.